# How to Activate Audit trail in Siebel 8 for local databases?

Tags: siebel, audit-trail

How to Activate Audit trail in Siebel 8 for local databases?

Answer (score 0):

There's an article about this on Siebel Unleashed called *[Configuring Siebel Audit Trail](http://siebelunleashed.com/configuring-siebel-audit-trial/)*.  I believe it's about Siebel 8.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Siebel Remote only applies/generate audit trail records when syncing with the server.

Thus, your local audit trail will always be empty. Also, that table tends to get very big which is not a good thing for remote.